# Containment of Bruhat cells on flag variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb C$, $B_0$ a Borel subgroup, $X$ the flag variety of $G$, $\mathbb O$ a $B_0$-orbit on $X$.

> Can we always find a Borel subgroup $B_x$ so that the open $B_x$-orbit
> $\mathbb O'$ contains $\mathbb O$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Resolved on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366920/containment-of-bruhat-cells-on-flag-variety). Thanks to imakhlin.